# WinDBG debugging a C++ /CLI module

Tags: debugging, c++-cli, windbg

I'm trying to use WINDBG to debug a C++/CLI module loaded in some application (Autodesk Revit). The problem is that the breakpoints set in unmanaged class methods are not hit. I have this class :

```
class NativeGeometryShape {
public :
    NativeGeometryShape()
        : width_(10), height_(12)
    {}

    int GetArea() const;

private :
    int width_;
    int height_;
};
```

Examining the symbol gives the following info :

```
0:000> x addon_revit2014!Native*
<MSIL:58bd350c         > addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::GetArea (void)
<MSIL:58bd1264         > addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::NativeGeometryShape (void)
58bd3500          addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::GetArea (<no parameter info>)
58bd3520          addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::GetArea (<no parameter info>)
58bd1258          addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::NativeGeometryShape (<no parameter info>)
```

So I'm using the bm command to setup some breakpoints :

```
0:000> bm addon_revit2014!Native*
      1: <MSIL:58bd350c         > @!"addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::GetArea"
      2: <MSIL:58bd1264         > @!"addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::NativeGeometryShape"
      3: 58bd3500          @!"addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::GetArea"
      4: 58bd3520          @!"addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::GetArea"
      5: 58bd1258          @!"addon_revit2014!NativeGeometryShape::NativeGeometryShape"
```

However these breakpoints are never hit, even though objects of the class are instantiated and the member functions called.
Any ideas ?

Comment: i never debugged c++ cli, however, my intuition told me that you set breakpoints on MSIL which was not jitted yet. you can try sos's !bpmd to set breakpoint

Comment: Another possible fix would be to put the non-managed class inside `#pragma unmanaged`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting access breakpoint on the members, and see when they are accessed, and from which function (ba r1 )